# Laravel blade button foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show one or more JPG files with a button, I use a `foreach` loop to show these images but currently I get 2 buttons when I have 2 files. How can I get only one button even if I have multiple images.

```
@foreach($letter->documents AS $document)
  @for($page = 1; $page <= $document->pages; $page++)
    <input onclick="window.open('{{ '/send/'.$letter->id.'/documents/'.$document->id.'/'.$page.'/778x1008'}}')" value="View PDF example" type="button" class="left"></input>
  @endfor
@endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel loops have an inherit `$loop` variable of which documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable).

In short one could use:

```
@foreach($letter->documents AS $document)
  //Show image
  @if ($loop->last)
    //Create button
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much milo526 for you help it worked for me